# liferay increase username length

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am aware that **liferay** concatenates the firstname with lastname for the **username** fields example the one found in table contact.

I need the username to be > 75 characters long (which is the default column length) as the first name and last name have to be at <= 40 characters long.

I tried to manually increase the column width but I get exceptions that another column related to length is too short. I am aware of the portal-model-hints.xml file to resize a column for example, but I am sure there is a better way to modify all the columns at one go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/16132968) should help you. Altering the DB once set up is done and adding a hook to change the validation logic. Refer the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to create EXT for this.

Please follow below steps to make changes.

1.Create file named as ext-model-hints.xml  and put it into "ext-impl/src/META-INF/" folder of EXT.

2.Make the entry as mentioned below

```
   <model name="Fully Qualified path of Model">
       <field name="column name" type="String">
           <hint name="max-length">200</hint>
       </field>
   </model>
```

1. deploy the EXT and restart the server.Changes should reflect.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a FullNameGenerator and a ScreenNameGenerator to bypass the issue and set them to their respective factories via liferay's reflection utilities (PortalClassInvoker) as some portal classes are hidden due to some classloader restrictions.